# Mysterious Memory Leak - NSString Autorelease Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

Even though I'm using NSAutoreleasePool in a tight loop, the following line in the method below is causing me to get memory warnings and ultimately crashing my app (by commenting out that line, the problem goes away).  Anyone have an idea why this is the case?

```
filepath = [docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

-(void)fileCleanup
{
    NSString *documentspath = [AppSession documentsDirectory];
    NSString *docpath = [documentspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"docs"];
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *files = [filemanager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:docpath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"fileCleanup");
    if(files != nil && [files count] > 0)
    {
        BOOL deletefile;
        NSString *filepath;
        NSAutoreleasePool *readPool;
        NSString *testfile;
        NSString *file;

        for(file in files) 
        {
            deletefile = YES;

            for (testfile in allFiles) {
                readPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

                //line below is causing memory leak!
                filepath = [docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
                //if([filepath isEqualToString:testfile])
                //{
                   // deletefile = NO;
                   // break;
                //} 
                [readPool drain];
            }

            if(deletefile)
            {
                [self logText:[@"\nD: " stringByAppendingString:[@"docs/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]]];
                [filemanager removeItemAtPath:[docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:NULL];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might already be tight on memory so the line you mention might just be the one allocating the few remaining bytes that reach the high water mark. In the outer loop, you create a lot of strings for logging purposes that won't be released until the main loop has finished processing the current event. Your autorelease pools won't help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the inner "for" loop with the Objective C equivalent of the php in_array() function and the memory issues disappeared!

```
    NSUInteger matchint = [allFiles indexOfObject:[docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
    if(matchint != NSNotFound)
        deletefile = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

The break statement was dropping you out of your inner for loop without calling -drain on the NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: I spotted that after posting and still didnt solve my problem when I corrected.